# Is there anyway that I can display SQL query in html?

Tags: html, css

I'm curious if there's any way to display SQL query(**Just the statement itself, not the result**) with proper format in HTML document. I'm using it for documentation/demo purpose.

For example here you can display a SQL query like this(with gray background):

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
```

The only thing I came close is using Wells from Bootstrap(which looks very similar to above). But I'm wondering if there's any other way of doing it. If it has functionality of syntax highlighting too, that would be great.

Comment: Silly question, but couldn't you just put the SQL on your web page, maybe inside a <pre> tag if you want to format it nicely?

Comment: Can you please put your SQL and what db engine you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM USERS";

<code><?php echo $query; ?></code>

<pre><?php echo $query; ?></pre>
```